# JSON schema validation when type is an array of strings

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I am trying to implement a validator for JSON schema using the v4 Draft.
For the "type" keyword, it can be either a string or an array of strings as written [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.2)
In the case if it is an array, how the validation will work?

For example: the keyword "maximum" is valid for numeric types while the keyword "maxLength" is valid for the string type.
If I specify a type array of both "integer" and "string" will both keywords be valid or none or what?

Answer (score 0):

If the value being validated is numeric, then `maximum` will be used for validation.  If the value being validated is a string, then `maxLength` will be used for validation.

If `type` is not present, or it contains a matching type, then other keywords are used based on the type of the *data*, not what's in `type`.

Comment: Can you explain why the validation does not kick in on this [link](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html#/68b8d6e017c73eeeed38)